# Example of Continuous Function Not Differentiable at Endpoints of Closed Interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and is differentiable on the *open* interval $(a, b)$.

I am looking for a function where the (one-sided) derivatives at the endpoints do not exist, but specifically where the derivative is not 'infinite' at the endpoints? That is, $f$, such that

$$ \lim \limits_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h} $$

does not exist, and is not $\pm \infty$?

More generally, it seems to me that there is not really any useful 'criteria' for when the above limit does or doesn't exist- am I broadly correct in thinking this?

Comment: It exists when it exists. There is really not much to say here, other than the fact that if $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok - so there doesn't seem to be any really useful criterion (given the setup) for differentiabilty at the end points. Could you perhaps give an example where the derivative does not exist at the end points?

Comment: Take $f\colon[-1,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, for instance.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you - I can't believe I missed that! I've updated the question slightly to look for examples where the derivative doesn't just blow up though.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ has infinite derivatives at the endpoints, that's not what OP wants, as I understand it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That is correct, but I failed to originally put this in the question and Jose did answer before I had added this. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x)=x(1-x)\,\sin\frac{1}{x(1-x)}$ on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0.$ It's obviously continuous, and the difference quotient at the endpoints takes all values between -1 and 1.

Comment: Ah yes! I really need to start recognising when the standard examples such as $x \sin{\frac1x} $ (a sort of one-sided version of your example) can be used. Much appreciated.

Comment: They are very handy, and you can fine-tune them, to be differentiable, but with infinite length of the graph, for instance.